# convert without using pre defined method

Tags: c

I am implementing a function takes array  and return the its value , the code seem to be all good except for the converting part .

```
#include <stdio.h>

int length=10;

int function (char s){ 
int n=0,i;
for ( i = 0; i < length; i++)
     {  
printf(" %d = %x   %c \n ", i, s, );
n = n * 10 + ;  
 s++;
     }

return n;
}

int main(){
char p[10];
printf("enter string ");
scanf("%s",p);
printf("\n");

int number;
number =function(p);
printf("  %d \n",&number);
return 0;}
```

Comment: as you can see from the output , not the preferable result .

Comment: When compiled  there comes loads of warnings with your code .

Comment: Use `%p` instead of `%x` to print addresses.

Comment: Please add sample input and both current and expected output. See [the Help Centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: C does not support _methods_, only _functions_.

Comment: Please consistently indent the code.  do not use tabs for indenting.  Suggest 4 spaces per level of indent and that allows numerous indent levels across a page and is wide enough to be visible even with variable width fonts.

Comment: for readability by us humans, do not place more than one statement per line. do not declare more than one variable per statement.

Comment: the call to `scanf()` for a string will fail if the string contains any `white space`. and will allow the user to overrun the input buffer resulting in undefined behaviour and can lead to a seg fault event

Comment: several lines in the posted code fail to compile, for instance: `n = n * 10 + ;`  Just what is that trailing `+` expected to do?

Comment: when printing, do not use `&`, however, with `scanf()` do need address of variables, (note: in C, the name of an array degrades to the address of the first byte of the array.)

Comment: this line: `int length=10;` should be: `#define LENGTH (10)  Note: by convention, #define values are all caps with the root words separated by underscores.  Note: when #defining an expression always wrap it in parens to avoid any 'text replacement' errors

Comment: the posted code, in the function main(), has a `magic` number.  `magic` numbers make the code more difficult to understand and a real headache to debug/maintain.  Suggest using #define's or an enum to give `magic` numbers meaningful names and use that meaningful name throughout the code

Comment: the call to `function()` from main() passes a pointer argument, but the actual function is expecting an char argument.

Comment: the function: `function()` fails to check that the current character in the string 's' is numeric and stop if the char is not numeric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`char *p[10];` should be `char p[10];`. You want an array of characters, not an array of pointer to characters.

`printf(" returned value %d \n",&number);` should be `printf(" returned value %d \n", number);`, because you want to print the number, not the address of the number.

With this 2 changes it works: http://ideone.com/HMjoRZ

Comment: i had like to use the pointers ,  but the second change in print statement is correct , it worked after I removed the & from number , thank you .

Answer (score 0):

Write

```
printf(" returned value %d \n", number);
                                ^^^^^^
```

Otherwise using `&number` you are trying to output the address of `number` as an integer value.

As for the function itself then it could be written the following simplified way

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int convert( const char *s )
{ 
    int numericValue = 0;
    enum { POSITIVE, NEGATIVE } sign = POSITIVE; 

    while ( isspace( ( unsigned char )*s ) ) ++s;

    if ( *s == '-' ) sign = NEGATIVE;
    if ( *s == '-' || *s == '+' ) ++s;

    for ( ; isdigit( ( unsigned char )*s ); ++s ) numericValue = 10 * numericValue + *s - '0';

    if ( sign == NEGATIVE ) numericValue = -numericValue;

    return numericValue;
}

int main( void )
{
    printf( "%d\n", convert( "-12345" ) );
    printf( "%d\n", convert( "+12345" ) );
    printf( "%d\n", convert( "12345" ) );
    printf( "%d\n", convert( "12A345" ) );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
-12345
12345
12345
12
```

Comment: thank you , that was a tiny mistake I always do . it worked .

Comment: this is very advanced , I can see you have handled the negative and positive number . very helpful thank you .

Answer (score 0):

there were many problems with the posted code, that are fixed in the following.  This compiles cleanly and performs the desired function and handles non numeric input correctly and performs appropriate error checking

caveat: only handles positive numbers

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h> // < for the 'isdigit()' function

// Use #define rather than a variable
#define LENGTH          10

// use this #define pattern for variable max length in scanf()
#define str(x)          # x
#define xstr(x)         str(x)

int function (char *s) // passed in parameter is a pointer to string
{
    int n=0;
    int i;

    for ( i = 0; s[i]; i++) // terminate loop when NUL byte encountered
    {
        if( isdigit( s[i] ) ) // < note check for valid input
        {
            //printf(" %d = %x   %c \n ", i, s, );
            n = (n * 10) + (s[i]-'0') ;
        }
        else
        { // then char not in range '0'...'9'
            break;
        }
    }

    return n;
}

int main( void )
{
    char p[ LENGTH+1 ]; // < note correction +1 because scanf adds NUL byte

    printf("enter string ");
    if( 1 != scanf("%"xstr(LENGTH)"s",p) )
    { // then scanf failed
         perror( "scanf failed for input string" );
         exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, scanf successful

    printf("%s\n", p);

    int number;
    number =function(p);
    printf("  %d \n",number);  // < note correction
    return 0;
}
```